# Update multiple values in same document in MongoDB using C# using

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-.net-driver

I am in the process of creating a lightweight wrapper class for MongoDB which will be used in my project. I am stuck at a point where I want to update multiple values in the same document. I am unable to figure out a proper solution for this.

My document in MongoDB looks like this

```
_id : "7241b664-4943-4929-bcbf-18726cb74eeb"
Patterns :"Pattern1"
Description :"M1"
Update : "U1"

_id    :    "b6c8beb9-01a5-4a59-b5da-f2ef6501a86b"
Patterns : "Pattern2"
Description  : "M2"
Update  : "U2"

_id    :    "9cd91fa0-3e49-413a-8ad4-c1830aaae841"
Patterns   :  "Pattern3"
Description : "M3"
Update    :    "U3"

_id    :    "b597d1ec-160c-4c2c-8b67-ff36f4aa51ca"
Patterns     :    "Pattern4"
Description    :    "M4"
Update    :    "U4"
```

Now let's say I want to update `Description` and `Update` fields for

```
   _id = "7241b664-4943-4929-bcbf-18726cb74eeb"
```

I am creating a generic lightweight library for MongoDB and the clients consuming it should not depend on the `MongoDB.Driver` or BSON or any of its DLL file.

When I want to update a single field for a single record in the document I can do that. Below is my code for this:

```
 public void Update<T, Tfield>(string collectionName, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<T, Tfield>> field, Tfield value)
    {
        if (filter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filter is empty");
        var collection = GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
        var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(field, value);
        collection.UpdateMany(filter, update);
    }
```

Using this is something like this:

```
public void TestMongoUpdate()
    {
        var p = new RegexPatterns();
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var collection = "MessagePatterns";
        //var filter = "{ _id: 'def8437e-d101-453e-a498-05e129b8dd39'}";
        var mongo = new Mongo(connectionString);
        mongo.DatabaseName = "MongoDB";
        var id = "7241b664-4943-4929-bcbf-18726cb74eeb";
        var pattern = new RegexPatterns();
        pattern._id = id;
        pattern.Patterns = "mypattern";
        pattern.Description = "mydesc";
        mongo.Update<RegexPatterns, string>(collection, (x => x._id == id),(y => y.Patterns),pattern.Patterns);
        Assert.True(true);
    }
```

With the above test method, I can update `Patterns` value for the provided id. Now I want to update `Patterns` and `Description` field for the provided id, but I am banging my head on the wall without actually making this method work to update multiple fields.

I tried the below test case to do this, but it is not working. I am doing something terribly wrong.

```
public void TestMongoUpdateMulti()
    {
        var p = new RegexPatterns();
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var collection = "MessagePatterns";
        //var filter = "{ _id: 'def8437e-d101-453e-a498-05e129b8dd39'}";
        var mongo = new Mongo(connectionString);
        mongo.DatabaseName = "MongoDB";
        var id = "7241b664-4943-4929-bcbf-18726cb74eeb";
        var pattern = new RegexPatterns();
        pattern._id = id;
        pattern.Patterns = "mypattern";
        pattern.Description = "mydesc";
        mongo.Update<RegexPatterns, RegexPatterns>(collection, (x => x._id == id), (y => pattern), pattern);
        Assert.True(true);
    }
```

How can I fix this?

This is in C# using .NET standard 2.0 and latest `MongoDB.Driver`.

Comment: Have you had a look at how [Mongo does it](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Driver)?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you need a generic method that updates two and exactly two properties, like `Update<T, Tfield, Tfield2>(...)` ?

Comment: Not exactly two properties. To be correct mutiple values